# Update progress bar from values obtained from different class

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I have to an `Activity` in which I have to update the progress of the `ProgressBar`, with a value got from different class.

In download class I used this function to calculate progress..

```
public void publishDownloadProgress(long lengthoffile, long bytesDownloaded){
        mFileLength = lengthoffile;
        totalBytesDownloaded = bytesDownloaded;
        mProgress = ((totalBytesDownloaded*100)/mFileLength);    
    }
```

and this to get progress

```
public long getDownloadProgress(){
       return mProgress;
   }
```

But when I use `getDownloadProgress()`; in my `Activity`, I only get `0` which is understandable since it only gets it one time.

But what I like instead is a series of continuous  progress values using which I want to update my `ProgressBar`, how to do that?

Comment: Are you using an AsyncTask or a Handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call **getDownloadProgress()** multiple times.

and set some time between two call.

You are getting zero because first time progress may be zero.
wait for some time 4ex **Thread.sleep(50000);**

then again call **getDownloadProgress()** you will get updated value